# Why do I have clumps of grass in my bathtub after a sewage overflow?

Tags: plumbing

The washer drained and two bathroom toilets violently overflowed. Nasty, stinky, sewage and water came up in both bathroom tubs, the shower drain and both sinks as well. I could hear water gurgling in the kitchen sink. The water has finally drained from the bathtubs and there is dirt and clumps of grass in the bottom of the tubs.

What is going on?

Comment: Are you on a septic system or city sewers? Your symptoms sound like a collapse of the main line.  Any construction nearby?  You need a plumber with a video camera.

Comment: I don't think it is a collapse of the main line.  You wouldn't get grass you would get dirt.  It seems like a major blockage in the main sewer line and maybe grass clippings caught in sewer or open cleanouts are coming back.  Really weird issue.

Comment: Bad backflow preventer?

Comment: I would really guess this was an issue with the sewer side.  If you do not have septic and get your sewer service from city then you need to call them and ask them what is going on.  Someone needs to be out at your house soon.

Answer (score 2):

In many small towns, or towns that used to be small, when the sewer system was constructed the people in charge decided to save money by connecting the storm drain system into the sewage collection. The idea is that all the rain water will be collected at the sewage facility and treated together. What usually happens after the sewage handling has been outgrown by the population or there has been a very large rain is that the sewage system will backup into the rain water collection and causes problems. What I suspect has happened in your case is that people mowed their lawns and the grass clippings ended up in the rainwater collection drains. The rainwater emptied into the sewer system and then the system (unfortunately) backed up into your house. I don't think you have more to worry about past the fact that your town has a sewer problem. Though I probably wouldn't eat any  fish you catch nearby.